# Python Open CV overlay image on contour of a big image

Tags: python, opencv

I have a big image of shape where i'm looking to overlap an image on a shape based on the contour

I have this image [image]

I have this contur where it is detecting the shape and color of the image

[image]

I want to place an image on this shape

I want to custom resize the image

[image]

Out Put Desired:-

[image]

Code:-

```
if color == "blue" and shape == "pentagon":
    A_img = cv2.imread("frame.png")
    print(A_img)
    x_offset=y_offset=50
    B_img[y_offset:y_offset+A_img.shape[0], x_offset:x_offset+A_img.shape[1]] = A_img
```

That code is not working the monkey is getting printed on the top left

Comment: What is `the appropriate solution`? You should use `cv2.resize` to resize your `A_img` .

Comment: @MadLee this code is getting printed on topleft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a working solution. Hope it is what you were looking for.

**Code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('C:/Users/524316/Desktop/shapes.png', 1)
monkey = cv2.imread('C:/Users/524316/Desktop/monkey.png', 1)

image2 = image.copy()
image3 = image.copy()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
#cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)

_, cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for c in cnts:

    #---- making sure to avoid small unwanted contours ---
    if cv2.contourArea(c) > 150:

        #--- selecting contours having 5 sides ---
        if len(cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * cv2.arcLength(c, True), True)) == 5:


            cv2.drawContours(image2, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

            #--- finding bounding box dimensions of the contour ---
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            print(x, y, w, h)

            #--- overlaying the monkey in place of pentagons using the bounding box dimensions---
            image3[y:y+h, x:x+w] = cv2.resize(monkey, (np.abs(x - (x+w)), np.abs(y - (y+h))))


cv2.imshow('image2', image2)
cv2.imshow('image3', image3) 

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: But If I want this to be more Dyanmic like I want to place the monkey on red triangle ?

Comment: I have not incorporated the color detection part yet. In order to do what you want I would first create two dictionaries one for the colors and other for shapes. The `color` dictionary would contain the color ranges in HSV or LAB. The `shape` dictionary would contain the number of sides.  Based on the input it would split `red triangle` into `red` and `triangle`, then find the corresponding color range and shape.